# SPKI Public Key to Compressed Public Key

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, keys, compression, x.509

I currently have a DER-encoded X.509 ECC SECP256K1 public key, also known as SubjectPublicKeyInfo (SPKI) from AWS KMS. How do I convert it to a 66 hexadecimal compressed public key string?

Comment: My (not really cryptographic) recommendation, on a system that has OpenSSL (or equivalent like LibreSSL), is `openssl ec -inform d -in file -pubin -conv_form compressed -noout -text` and lightly edit the result (usually an awk or sed oneliner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is for the standard 256-bit Elliptic Curve [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1). It wants the key in the format described in [sec1v2, section 2.3.3 Elliptic-Curve-Point-to-Octet-String Conversion](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.3.3), with point compression, that is per 2.1/2.2.1/2.3/2.4

The desired compressed public key starts with byte `02` or `03` (with the same parity as the $Y$ coordinate), followed by the $X$ coordinate in big-endian notation over 32 bytes. Further conversion to hexadecimal makes that a 66-character string.

To decode the DER-encoded public key SubjectPublicKeyInfo or X.509 certificate, one can use [this online tool](https://lapo.it/asn1js/), which accepts hex and base64. As this [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/225506) points out, it will normally show the (point representative of) the public key either

- in a bitstring which data is in the uncompressed format of 65 bytes (520 bits), the first of which is `04`, followed by the $X$ coordinate and the $Y$ coordinate in big-endian notation each over 32 bytes. In order to convert to compressed format, we can replace the initial `04` with `02` or `03` (determined so that it has the same parity as the last byte), and remove the last 32 bytes.
- in a bitstring which data already is in the desired compressed format of 33 bytes (264 bits), the first of which is `02`or `03`.

Note: In other conversion contexts I have met $X$ and $Y$ coordinates encoded as ASN.1 integer in the public key. Facing this, the textbook solution is to use an ASN.1 library. When doing without, be careful that the ASN.1 encoding of integers has variable length, so that it may be needed to remove one leading `00` (≲50% of the cases), or add one `00` (<0.4% of the cases) or even more (<0.002%).

Note: One might want to check that $X$, and $Y$ if available, form a valid secp256k1 public key, that is: for $p=2^{256}-2^{32}−977$ (the prime field order) it holds

- $0<X<p$
- if $Y$ is available, that $0<Y<p$ and $X^3+7-Y^2\bmod p=0$
- otherwise, that $(X^3+7)^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p=1$

Comment: No; SPKI itself is ASN.1 but the 'raw' EC public point within it is not, and will not be decoded to X and Y by any ASN.1 tool, even if both are present. Rather it is already _either_ X9.62/SEC1 uncompressed 04 {X} {Y} _or_ compressed 02/03 {X}. See rfc5480 2.2 and previously rfc3279 2.3.5.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thanks for the correction.